# Expectation of XYYX

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random square matrices. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $E[X] = Z$, $E[Y] = Z$.

What is  $E[XYY^TX^T]$? ($Y^T$ and $X^T$ are the transposes of $Y$ and $X$)

Is it equal to $Z^2(Z^2)^T$? I believe it is not, but I don't know how to prove or disprove it. I can't use the product of expectations since $X$ and $Y$ are not independent with respect to themselves.

Thank you.

Comment: Even for $1\times1$ matrices this may be either true or false depending on the actual distributions. (Knowing the expectation is not enough). But in most cases false.

Comment: Suppose each of $X$ and $Y$ is either $-I$ or $I$ with probability 1/2. Then $Z=0$, but your product is $I$ in every case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any formula that can help with this product, maybe by knowing the variance of $X$ and $Y$?